# Make text clickable with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code

```
<li id="one" class="hot">figs <div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="three" class="hot">honey<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
```

What I want to do is make this '[x]' clickable and when I click it, this li will be hidden. So how to do it in JS?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: <li id="one" class="hot">figs <div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="three" class="hot">honey<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>

Comment: add `html` code in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.closeit').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLjmy72h/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using jQuery (you mentioned it in the tag).

It adds a listener to the 'click' event of your [x] divs, and hides the parent li.

You should go through [this article](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) to learn more about jQuery DOM events.

```js
$('.closeit').on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="one" class="hot">figs <div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="three" class="hot">honey<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your JS code:

```
$('.closeit a').click(function(){
    $(this).hide()
})
```

And in your HTML:

```
<li id="one" class="hot">figs 
    <div class="closeit">
        <a>[x]</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: no need for the <a> element at all, check my answer for working code using just OP html code

Comment: @xShirase i added to give to the user the feedback that is an clickable element, but is true is not needed.

Comment: a css rule to change the pointer would do the trick :p

Comment: @xShirase true, but just to don't make it more complex :)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function of jquery.

Something like below.

```js
$('.closeit ').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="one" class="hot">figs <div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
<li id="three" class="hot">honey<div class="closeit">[x]</div></li>
```

Comment: @james see updated answer